# css difference between firefox and Internet Explorer

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox

My css code:

```
.main-slider{
    background-color: #CCC;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    width: 650px;
    height: 300px;
    overflow:hidden;    
}

.main-slider .slider-large-image{
    float:left;
    }
.main-slider .slider-sidebar{
    float:right;
    }
```

My HTML Code is [here](http://pastebin.com/7pPwpcYi).

**I want to get as can be seen in Internet Explorer.**
[image: Internet Explorer]
[image: Firefox]

Comment: Please post up your HTML markup code

Comment: You should put this whole thing into a working jsFiddle demo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding:

```
.main-slider .slider-sidebar{
    float:right;
    width: 110px;
}
```

Comment: thank you okey but how can i adjust the position of images according to border?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should just set img as `display:block;`

[this is the result.](http://jsfiddle.net/maxisam/Su7T7/)

if you want to adjust the position, try margin-right / margin-top